# Time changes automatic in the input box while I open datetime picker

Tags: javascript, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using jquery date-time picker in input box. 
initialized with below code

```
minDate: 0/new Date(); (tried both)
```

Input box has some old date-time when I click for edit it open date-time picker, it disable old date and old time but it also change time in input box to current time if input box time is earlier than current time.

You can see here live example

http://jsfiddle.net/bhupendra21589/perd7pc6/

Comment: Which date picker are you using? The jQuery UI one? Can you post your code as a jsFiddle? Can you please try to reformat your question and make it clear what's hapenning now vs. what's meant to happen? Also, is that code copy pasted from your code, because the minDAte should be minDate, without a capitalised A. That could be throwing it off

Comment: can you post a fiddle or an equivalent example please?

Comment: Which library you are using currently??

Comment: jquery date time picker.

Comment: added jsfiddle example.

Comment: Fyi, you don't have to include `minDate` at all. Do you want there to be a minimum date? If so, what?

Comment: Ya I need min date..so that user can not select backdate.

Comment: So then what is your issue exactly? It seems to work as expected. It stops you from selecting anything previous to the current date/time.

Comment: If current time is higher than time in input box, and you click into text box, datepicker open and it change time to current time. may be geographic issue, you can change value of input box according to your location.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var d = new Date()
$( '#duedate' ).datetimepicker({
    minDate: '0',
    minTime:d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes(),
    formatTime:'H:i'
});
```

I hope this solves the issue

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/adityashankert/perd7pc6/17/